# SCP is not working after making gitbash as default shell in windows server 2022

Tags: git-bash

It appears that SCP (Secure Copy Protocol) functions seamlessly when PowerShell is set as the default shell on both VMs running Windows Server 2022. However, when Git Bash is selected as the default shell, SCP encounters connection issues and fails to transfer files, resulting in a "connection lost" error message.

Comment: Interesting. What's your question? (ideally one that can be solved by programming)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi , actually I have two window server 2022 VM's . Scp is working fine when we select Power shell as default shell.I installed GIT on both the VM's and I configured gitbash as default shell on both the VM's. Now SCP is not working and showing connection lost error